# Is there a possibility to change default text "connected user/s" on CkEditor

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor

Is there a possibility to change the default "connected users" text with any custom text? I cannot seem to find anything about. FE is written in Vue.

[users connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGCU5.png)

Comment: Which version are you using, 4 or 5 ? Also, could you provide a reproduction link please ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this documentation page (v5): https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/collaboration/real-time-collaboration/users-in-real-time-collaboration.html#installation-and-configuration

It looks like the whole thing is handled by the `RealTimeCollaborativeEditing` plugin that is automatically imported and enabled. The docs gives indication on how to change the styling of the various connected users.

The `PresenceList` plugin only have 3 options:

- `container`
- `collapseAt`
- `onClick`

In short, you cannot edit the wording there, but you could probably remove the plugin or hide/customize it with CSS.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, that is not editable.